# Loading a custom key store in Google App Engine Java application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, https, keystore, urlfetch

I want to open a **HTTPS** connection in a Google App Engine app using the [URLFetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview) service. To be able **to verify the SSL certificate of the server my app is talking to, I am using my own keystore file**. I want to read this file in a [warmup request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Warmup_Requests) when my app is loaded i.e. before any HTTPS requests are performed. The keystore file is part of my WAR file.

```
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());  
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myKeystoreFile"), "password".toCharArray());  
trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);  

TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();  
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");  
sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);  

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

I cannot use this approach, however, because while HttpURLConnection is on the GAE's JRE whitelist, HttpsUrlConnection is not.

Is there another way to use a custom keystore in GAE? I did not find any information on this in the GAE docs. **It looks like while Google's URLFetch service supports HTTPS, the keystore cannot be customized.** Is this correct?

If this isn't possible, is the approach still valid in general? Or **is there a different approach that does still allow me to verify the SSL certificate?**

**UPDATE**

In 2009, App Engine developer Nick Johnson from Google said on https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine-python/C9RSDGeIraE/discussion:

> The urlfetch API doesn't allow you to specify your own client 
>   certificates, so unfortunately what you want to achieve is not 
>   currently possible.

**Is this still correct?** If every HTTP(s) request in App Engine relies on URLFetch this would mean that custom certificates just cannot be used at all in GAE.

Comment: As it turns out there is an open issue for this on [GAE's Google Code site](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3719).

Comment: What would be required to support this on App Engine? **Can someone from Google outline what would have to be done to implement this?**

Comment: Leviticus says he implemented this using the Apache HTTP client, see http://esxx.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-apaches-httpclient-on-google-app.html. I am still trying to understand his approach. Did anyone give this a try?

He put the source into subversion here: http://svn.berlios.de/svnroot/repos/esxx/trunk/jee/org/esxx/js/protocol

Comment: Actually, HttpsUrlConnection is in the whitelist: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist. Nevertheless, this restriction is for the Standard Environment; you can use any library you'd like for SSL connections in the Flexible Environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should sign up as a **[trusted tester](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/features#Trusted_Tester_Features)** for **[Outbound sockets support](https://docs.google.com/a/pogoapps.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0)**. Under **Desired Features** they enlist SSL. If more parts of the JDK SSL API would be supported building something like this would be simple.

Answer (score 4):

I was recently facing the same issue and using the HttpClient implementation packaged with appengine-api-stubs worked for me.

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.18</version>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
// create SSL Context which trusts your self-signed certificate
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myKeystoreFile"), "password".toCharArray());
trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

// register your trusting SSL context
Protocol.registerProtocol("https",
        new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory) new SocketFactoryWrapper(sslContext.getSocketFactory()), 443));

// make the https call
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("https://myendpoint.com");
httpclient.executeMethod(httpget);
System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
```

This does essentially the same thing as

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

But for one reason or another app engine doesn't block it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem... I needed a `keystore.p12` to call a foreign web service but had no chance loading it from the classpath. The only way I was able to use it was to put it in e.g. `/WEB-INF/keystore.p12` and load it from there.

```java
ServletContext context = getContext();
URL resourceUrl = context.getResource("/WEB-INF/keystore.p12");
```

Comment: Perhaps its a java policy issue. Did you edit the policy file and allow all (as a test)?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Appengine API 1.9.56 and what Dima suggested with

```
Protocol.registerProtocol("https",
    new Protocol("https", (ProtocolSocketFactory) new SocketFactoryWrapper(sslContext.getSocketFactory()), 443));
```

is not working anymore. Therefore I do not need the `appengine-api-stubs` library, either.

However, `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` just works fine.

Here is my complete solution which solved my problem:

```
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mytruststore.jks");
    keystore.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Luckily `HttpsURLConnection` is not blacklisted anymore, as it was in the time the question was made.