# Are client side certificates supported in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pysimplesoap

I am developing a google app engine application, and I need to connect to a webservice using SOAP. I'm using pysimplesoap (patched with the code found [here](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/issues/detail?id=45)) to parse the xml, and fire a request with a client-side certificate. 
When I do this in a simple unit test from my local environment, it works, and I get a proper response from the webservice. 
However, when I run the exact same code from within app engine, I get this:

```
  File "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/blixem/model/communicate/communication_channel.py", line 60, in generate_soap_message_pysimplesoap
    response = client.SendDocument('LA.XML', 'TESTCASE', 'data')
  File "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/blixem/lib/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 152, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/blixem/lib/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 320, in wsdl_call
    response = self.call(method, *params)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/blixem/lib/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 215, in call
    self.xml_response = self.send(method, self.xml_request)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/workspace/blixem/lib/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 241, in send
    location,"POST", body=xml, headers=headers )
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1457, in request
    self.disable_ssl_certificate_validation)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1143, in __init__
    strict, timeout, proxy_info, ca_certs, disable_ssl_certificate_validation)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/httplib2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1092, in __init__
    raise NotSupportedOnThisPlatform()
NotSupportedOnThisPlatform
```

I did some reading, and discovered that client side certificates were not supported yet in the urlfetch service. Is this still the case? If so, is there a work-around?

Comment: Thanx Ingo, I'll look into this Outbound Sockets Support feature. Too bad client certificates are not supported.

Comment: Ingo, I would like to up-vote your comment, but Im fairly new to asking questions on stackoverflow, so please tell me how to do this up-voting on your comment (shouldn't we be up-voting answers instead of comments?)

Comment: You are right. I removed the comment and added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side certificates are currently not supported by GAE. You can use the URLFetch service over HTTPS. But you cannot use client certificates. You should try the [Outbound Sockets Support feature](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0) which is currently available in the [trusted tester program](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/features#Trusted_Tester_Features). It might whitelist the functionality you are looking for. I asked [a similar question for GAE/J before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766613/1769636).

If you really need it already either go with the outbound socket feature or run a proxy in [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

Comment: This is no longer true - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [BooTooMany's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392617/384617), it's now possible to do this with the excellent [`requests` library](http://python-requests.org) as long as the underlying code is using [sockets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/). Follow these steps to use it:

1. Sockets are [only available to paid apps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/). Make sure your app has billing enabled.
2. Install `requests` into your `lib/` directory. I'm currently using v2.21.0. Make sure **not** to monkeypatch `requests` to use the AppEngine adapters provided by `requests-toolbelt`, despite that being recommended by [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests). This makes `requests` use `urlfetch` instead of sockets, which is available for free apps but does not currently support client-side certificates.
3. In your `app.yaml`, enable the SSL library:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

4. In your `app.yaml`, enable sockets for the development server:

```
env_variables:
  GAE_USE_SOCKETS_HTTPLIB: 'yes'
```

Now you're ready to make requests with client certificates:

```py
import requests

def make_request(url):
    cert = ('cert_file.pem', 'key_file.pem')
    server_cert_file = 'server_cert_file.pem'
    return requests.get(url=url, cert=cert, verify=server_cert_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python SSL is now supported on GAE - see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/ssl_support

So it's now possible to use client-side certificates. From that webpage:

```
 # Example of a dynamic key and cert.
  datastore_record_k = ndb.Key('Employee', 'asalieri', 'Address', 1)
  datastore_record = datastore_record_k.get()
  key_str = datastore_record.key_str
  cert_str = datastore_record.cert
  ssl_server = ssl.wrap_socket(server_sock,
                              server_side=False,
                              keyfile=StringIO.StringIO(key_str),
                              certfile=StringIO.StringIO(cert_str),
                              cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                              ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23,
                              ca_certs=CERTIFICATE_FILE)
```

Comment: How would one go about to create a HTTPS request with `ssl.wrap_socket`, as the question mentions? Would that require implementing a lot of low-level HTTP communication logic, or could [`requests`](http://python-requests.org/) or another library use this somehow?